# Visual Studio Code With ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded [Visual Studio Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/code-vs) and try for a couple hours as common editor, and it works really amazing. But when I want to open my currently running ASP.Net MVC Project, it doesn't detect the project as working project, that I can't use the InteliSense provided for C#.

Can I open the ASP.Net MVC Project that created from Visual Studio? If can, then what should I do in order to achieve this?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012, the project using ASP.Net MVC 4.

Comment: Is this a web application project, or a web site "project"? In particular, is there a .csproj file or .vbproj file?

Comment: The reality is that you will have to convert it to a "real" vs code project. create a new vs code c# project and copy files etc. in it. then it will work. make sure you don't have .net dependencies that won't run in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Basically VSCode supports two project systems:

1. DNX projects with `project.json` and `global.json` files and
2. MSBuild projects.

The support for the latter is a bigger challenge and not yet perfect. If you have a `sln` and `csproj` files VSCode should detect that and start. Can you check the flame in the lower left if OmniSharp has started and can you check the log (Ctrl+L,L) for messages?

Answer (score 1):

open folder rather than just file and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I just tried what you said. I could be able to open my solution by using "File->Open Folder" option. And selected folder of my MyProject.sln file's root folder. And after all files reloaded, I clicked Extensions page of VSCode just to be sure if C# extension loaded or not. I clearly saw C# extension was enabled. If yours is not enabled, try to enable or redownload it. And you should be able to use C# Intellisense on every .cs files.

Answer (score 0):

it is just a code editor with some awesome features. You need to install Visual Studio (Community edition) to work on .net projects.

Comment: Hey there, that's not true. All you really need is the .netcore framework installed to get vscore to build, currently I don't have any Visual Studio installed but quite happily writing apps.

Comment: Wishfull thinking, yes it should be possible, but the reality is that in most times it won  t work.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code will not work with MVC 1-5 only with ASP.NET Core MVC (MVC 6). VS Code has very limited support for full framework applications:

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Desktop-.NET-Framework